# Is it possible to jump right to errors in Xcode output?

Tags: xcode

When I try to do an Xcode build and it fails, I usually get a long list of warning messages in the "Buildtime" screen on the lefthand side of my Xcode window. The actual error message (with the red exclamation mark) is usually way at the bottom, and I have to scroll for a few seconds to get to it. Also, when I do scroll to it, it then loads more warnings below, so I have to do the scrolling process several times.
Does anyone know if there's a way to either jump directly to the error message, or output all the messages to a file or something?

Comment: There’s a hot key for this. Can’t think of it off the top of my head currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's irritates, especially if you are working with react-native project where usually more than 3000 warnings and it takes ages to scroll to the bottom where errors usually shown.

How to scroll to the bottom:

1. Click on the any message in the "Buildtime" list
2. Press Option + down arrow

Comment: I didn't understood this response correctly (tried to press down arrow on the keyboard), but I found out later, what could be the point. So in the other words:
In the Issues Navigator, it is possible to collapse all sections of issues. To do that: press and hold the Command button and click the expander arrow in any of the section in the Issue Navigator pane.